# Change back button place from left bar button to right Bar button with reverse animation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

How can I change back button place to right bar button of embedded navigation and change the the icon from `<` to `>`?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

- Hide back button:

  ```
  navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES
  ```
- Add a right button with an image arrow:

  ```
  let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: ">", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(backTapped))
  navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton
  ```

the action of backTapped will pop the view controller from the navigation controller stack.

Let me know in the comments if this approach can resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks For your answer. I Do this But have a little problem. when I back to previous view then show the back button On it and I don't want To show it !!

Comment: I use :

let newView = sabtEnsheabViewController(nibName: "sabtEnsheabViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newView, animated: false)

but it show back button to another view


use this :

let newView = EnsheabSabteNamViewController(nibName: "EnsheabSabteNamViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.presentViewController(newView, animated: false, completion: nil)

it doesn't show navigationBar anymore

Comment: @AliSHelcid You need to write this code in every controller where you want this behaviour, try in the viewdidload

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do this. it's not a best Solution but is the one.

Answer (score 0):

I use :

let newView = sabtEnsheabViewController(nibName: "sabtEnsheabViewController", bundle: nil)

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newView, animated: false)

but it show back button to another view

use this :

let newView = EnsheabSabteNamViewController(nibName: "EnsheabSabteNamViewController", bundle: nil)

self.presentViewController(newView, animated: false, completion: nil)

it doesn't show navigationBar anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
 I use this way for change back button position.

   //put this code in viewDidLoad()


   navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
   navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " > ", style: .done,target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))


   //function to handle back navigation

   @objc func addTapped(){

    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
```